# How to get the package name of the app which access content provider of my app?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-package-managers

Actually i want some kind of Broadcast when any other app fetches the data from the content provider shared by my app

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use `Binder.getCallingUid()` to get uid of calling application.
then use `getPackageManager().getNameForUid(uid)` to get package name of calling app.

**Example:**

```
@Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        int code = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        String callingPackageName = getContext().getPackageManager().getNameForUid(
                Binder.getCallingUid());
        Log.d(TAG, "calling Package Name::" + callingPackageName);

        if (callingPackageName.equals(PKG_MY_PACKAGE)) {
           //do what you want
        }
        .
        .
        .
        return uri;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I'm pretty late, but in API19 and above you can just call

```
getCallingPackage();
```

inside your ContentProvider to do this trick.

Look at [Android Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#getCallingPackage()) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to do is check whether the caller is another app, you don't even need the package name - just compare the UIDs of [Binder.getCallingUid](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder#getCallingUid()) and [Process.myUid](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#myUid()):

```java
if (Binder.getCallingUid() != Process.myUid()) {
    // An external app has called this
}
```